# Regex CHECK constraint not working with SQL server

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, t-sql, check-constraints

im trying to reject all inputs not in the format "03 xxxx xxxx" so i created a table like

```
create table records
(
....
num varchar(255) NOT NULL,
...
CONSTRAINT num_check CHECK (num like '03 [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}')
)
```

which should (i think?) accept for example "03 1234 1234". but if i try to add this via sql manager i get an error with the message:
"the INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "num_check" "

at first i thought my Regex was off but ive tried it in a few other places and it accepts the example above. 
any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know you can't implement Regex in SQL Server without using a CLR assembly.  It doesn't have native Regex support like Oracle does...unless my memory has failed me.

Comment: i was following some thing i saw here. http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/714703-check-constraint-regular-expressions.html

Comment: So far, I've only found one DBE that supports posix regex constraints and it is Oracle (Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157662/is-there-a-database-engine-that-allows-for-queriable-field-constraint-specified). MS SQL and DB2 look like they have their own wildcard variant, which is unfortunate as you loose consistency of constraints between layers :(

Comment: Relevant QA on the DBA site... https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/266438/3690

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) does not work with regular expressions, it has its own, much simpler wildcard patterns, which only support `%`, `_` , `[a-z]`, and `[^a-z]`. That's it. `{4}` would not works, just like most regex features.
You should be able to use:

```
like '03 [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Another option, a little less repetitive:

```
declare @digitChar nvarchar(12)
set @digitChar = '[0-9]'
```

Where clause:

```
like '03 ' + replicate(@digitChar,4) + ' ' + replicate(@digitChar,4)
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/3251

Comment: that'll teach me for trying to make my Regex cleaner and short. Thanks Kobi

Comment: @TrewTzu - That's exactly the problem - `like` does not handle regular expressions - it's just the `[]` that is similar. Anyway, I've included another version - I did something very similar when checking for GUIDs, and didn't want `[0-9a-fA-F]` repeated 32 times...